# Ursina Python Engine: Lighting, Shadows And Bloom Effects

Tags: python, game-engine, shadow, ursina, bloom

I Am New To Ursana Engine And I Don't Know It Properly. But I Can Make Games In It. But The Problem Is That My Game Doesn't Have Any **<Shadows, Glow, Lighting or Bloom>**. So My Game Looks Dead.

Is There Any Way To Make My Game Look Good Using **<Shadows, Glow, Lighting and Bloom>** In Ursana Engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to import shaders from ursina and then apply directional light.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader 

app = Ursina()
EditorCamera()
Entity(model='plane', scale=10, color=color.gray, 
shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
Entity(model='cube', y=1, shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
pivot = Entity()
DirectionalLight(parent=pivot, y=2, z=3, shadows=True, rotation=(45, -45, 45))

app.run()
```

Comment: Also, how do you control the brightness of `AmbientLight`

Comment: As ursina is made from Panda3D then you can go to this [Panda3D Lightning Docs](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/programming/render-attributes/lighting) and see the [Coloured Lights Section](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/programming/render-attributes/lighting#colored-lights)

Comment: did you find it useful?

Comment: Somewhat, but I believe that there is a direct Ursina implementation I used a while ago, but I can't remember what it is. It should just be a parameter to AmbientLight()

Comment: Perhaps alpha=[whatever-value]? I will try it later.

Comment: I am also exited to know how to do so if you found something please tell me.

Comment: @Password-Classified i found the solution
 `AmbientLight(color = color.rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1))`

Comment: You can change the rgb values and alpha if you want

Answer (score 3):

You have to add lights and also apply `lit_with_shadows_shader` to entities that will receive shadow.

See more here: https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#DirectionalLight

Answer (score 0):

i got a problem with world generation, i use perlin_noise for it. the place where i spawn, has shadows(the lit_with_shadows_shader), but when i build more terrain, there are no more shadows.(i got a directional light)

Comment: You should ask a separate question mentioning this question.

Comment: You need to post this as a new question, not as an answer to this question

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34525731)